better_player, jitsi_meet_flutter_sdk , ExpoPlayer Version Compatibility
I have tow flutter packages better_player & jitsi_meet_flutter_sdk that uses
ExpoPlayer but with  different version of it I guess. the jitsi_meet_flutter_sdk overwrite the expoPlayer version making better_player crash. any thing I can do?
Log
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(error, MediaSource.Factory#setDrmSessionManagerProvider no longer handles null by instantiating a new DefaultDrmSessionManagerProvider. Explicitly construct and pass an instance in order to retain the old behavior., null, java.lang.NullPointerException: MediaSource.Factory#setDrmSessionManagerProvider no longer handles null by instantiating a new DefaultDrmSessionManagerProvider. Explicitly construct and pass an instance in order to retain the old behavior.
E/flutter (31742):  at com.google.android.exoplayer2.util.Assertions.checkNotNull(Assertions.java:174)
E/flutter (31742):  at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.hls.HlsMediaSource$Factory.setDrmSessionManagerProvider(HlsMediaSource.java:296)
E/flutter (31742):  at com.jhomlala.better_player.BetterPlayer.buildMediaSource(BetterPlayer.kt:424)
E/flutter (31742):  at com.jhomlala.better_player.BetterPlayer.setDataSource(BetterPlayer.kt:196)
E/flutter (31742):  at com.jhomlala.better_player.BetterPlayerPlugin.setDataSource(BetterPlayerPlugin.kt:277)
E/flutter (31742):  at com.jhomlala.better_player.BetterPlayerPlugin.onMethodCall(BetterPlayerPlugin.kt:151)
E/flutter (31742):  at com.jhomlala.better_player.BetterPlayerPlugin.onMethodCall(BetterPlayerPlugin.kt:138)

tried to force both to use the same expoPlayer version but nothing
